# How can I toggle a class to various items?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to toggle a class from various items. I mean, I have 5 divs with `.item` class inside a div with `.container` class. Can I toggle a new class to those 5 .items? Maybe with a loop?

I was trying to do it but it seems that the loop goes infinite.

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
</div>

<script>
   function myFunction () {
       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
       for (i=0; i<x.length; i+1) {
           x[i].classList.toggle('new-class');
       }
   }
</script>
```

I expect something like this at the end (maybe with some loop in JS):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item new-class"></div>
    <div class="item new-class"></div>
    <div class="item new-class"></div>
    <div class="item new-class"></div>
    <div class="item new-class"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... that was really easy I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the for loop and the classList.add() method.

```
function myFunction() {
   var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.add('new-class');
   }
}
```